# How do I submit a form with specific <li>s and have event handled by Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'd like to have a form submitted on the selection of any of a set of `<li>` elements. I have:

```
<form class="story_form" id="story_form">

     <textarea rows="3" name="story" class="form-control" placeholder="Share a story"></textarea>
     <br/>
     <div class="dropdown">
       <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">about ...
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" id="submit_purpose" onclick="story_form.submit();"><a href="#">Our Purpose <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title={{purpose}}></span></a></li>
          <!-- <li class="divider"></li> -->
          <li class="dropdown-header">or one of our principles ...</li>
          {{#each principles}}
            {{> principle}}
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </div>
 <br/>
</form>
```

with an event handler:

```
Template.inputStory.events({
 'submit .story_form'(event) {
  console.log(event);
 }
});
```

I'm testing with the first `<li>` but the event handler never gets called.

Thanks,
Glenn

Comment: That's too broad. Where is `principle` template? Why `onlick` in first `<li>`?

Comment: I haven't rolled it down to the `principle` part of the list. `onclick` in first `<li>` was just to see if I could get one `<li>` to submit

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "submit a `<li>`"? That just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have a `textarea` that I want users to submit via one of several options. That's why I am using a list (behind a dropdown toggle button). I'm happy to use a different UI design if someone can suggest something better.